# Problema de performance com fotos dentro de uma caixa de listagem com scroll

Tags: javascript, html, angular

**Explicação:**

Dentro de um container com scroll, tenho uma lista de dados que é carregado por duas  APIS, uma que traz os dados dos usuários e outra que carrega asyncronamente as fotos. Conforme as fotos começam a ser exibidas nessa caixinha, o sistema começa a travar, o problema é que são tantas fotos, que o navegador não aguenta, trava o rolamento da tela, e do container.

Pensando em uma solução, acredito que a melhor maneira de resolver isso seria limitar a quantidade de fotos que são acrescentadas no DOM enquanto eles não são necessárias:

> **Solução proposta:**
> A ideia para corrigir o problema é remover as fotos quando elas não estão sendo visualizadas dentro desse container, ou seja, na área escondida do scroller, eu removeria elas da tela através de uma simples condição booleana "showImage" nessa imagem.
> Isso evitaria uma sobrecarga da tela devido a enorme quatidade de imagens.

**Exemplo do uso da condição:**

```
<span class="mask-photo" *ngIf="showImage">
    <img class="user-definition-photo" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/ikmedia/woman.jpg?tr=w-200">
</span>
```

Resta agora saber como eu poderia identificar quais destas imagens não estão disponíveis visualmente.

**Como obter aquilo que não é enxergado?**

Então, chegamos ao ponto do problema em questão, de que maneira eu poderia identificar que uma imagem não está sendo enxergada dentro de desse container? Essa é a questão.

Aqui está um exemplo simples com menos imagens da modelagem que preciso:

[Fiddle de exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq2xund9/)

A mesma coisa se pensar o inverso, poderia talvez funcionar, como acionar uma classe de estilo apenas para o que está dentro da área visível do container.

[Outra referência](https://www.horadecodar.com.br/2021/05/27/como-verificar-se-elemento-esta-visivel-ao-scrollar-em-javascript/)

Comment: Para a situação que descreves eu recomendaria o uso de intersection observer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: @dfvc, obrigado pela dica, vou tentar ir por esse caminho.

Comment: Tem que testar bem os pressupostos. Em tese, o browser já determina o que tem na viewport e renderizar só o necessário, se o scroll dá problema há chance grande de ter elementos fazendo recálculo - ou simplesmente o "peso" é por falta de serialização apropriada da sua rotina de carga da API, tentando carregar tudo de uma vez. A parte de "detectar o que é visível", se separada da premissa inicial, acho que vira uma ótima pergunta, mas atualmente o post me dá impressão de relacionar problemas distintos. Um [mcve] com o problema de performance faz falta para aferir.

Comment: Lembrando que no site já tem posts detalhados de como carregar imagem com scroll, de repente em vez de aferir o retângulo bastaria ver se o scroll Y (ou X) chegou na imagem, sem complicar muito (mas ainda acho que se separar a parte de como detectar se um elementou está numa viewport ou retângulo, pode ser uma ótima pergunta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além da sugestão sobre Intersection Observer dada por [@dfvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/219641/dfvc), talvez possa fazer sentido, como está trabalhando com Angular, o uso de [Virtual Scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview).

Usando o `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` faz com que grandes listas de elementos sejam renderizadas de forma mais performática, visto que faz renderizar somente o que está visível na tela naquele momento.

**Exemplo de implementação**:

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Onde o ***cdkVirtualFor** substitui o ***ngFor** dentro do elemento `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`, suportando exatamente a mesma API como o `*ngFor` faz.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nncl, pode fazer sentido mesmo, vou experimentar, valeu! Tem como editar a pergunta e colocar um exemplo prático do uso desse componente, para ajudar outros da comunidade além de mim.

Comment: @IvanFerrer feito!