# Replicar evento IntersectionObserver para múltiplos scrollers

Tags: javascript, angular

Com base nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/567736/problema-de-performance-com-fotos-dentro-de-uma-caixa-de-listagem-com-scroll), que foi em parte resolvida através do método abaixo, surgiu uma outra dúvida, como eu poderia replicar esse evento, pois tenho um ninebox com 9 scrollers similares a este, ocorre que o método IntersectionObserver parece que só é chamado uma única vez quando carrega a página e não vejo ele processando nos 9 scrollers, eu tentei colocar isso em um foreach assim, pegando cada container com uma div, mas não funcionou:

```
 addImage:any[] = [
       "scroll_0_0_0",
       "scroll_1_1_0",
       "scroll_2_2_0",
       "scroll_3_0_1",
       "scroll_4_1_1",
       "scroll_5_2_1",
       "scroll_6_0_2",
       "scroll_7_1_2",
       "scroll_8_2_2"
    ];

observeDataImage() {

        this.addImagem
       .forEach(element => {

                let options = {
                    root:document.getElementById(element),
                    rootMargin: "0px",
                    threshold: 0.25
                };
                 /*
                   Nota: 0.25 é o limite da visibilidade de retorno do observador. 
                   Um único número ou uma matriz de números que indicam 
                   em qual porcentagem da visibilidade do alvo o retorno de chamada do 
                   observador deve ser executado. Se você deseja detectar apenas quando 
                   a visibilidade ultrapassar a marca de 50%, pode usar um valor de 0.5.
                 */
             

                const isIntersecting = (entry: IntersectionObserverEntry) =>
                entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0.25;

                const callback = (entries, observer) => {
                    console.log(entries)
                    entries.forEach(entry => {
                        const target = entry.target as HTMLElement;
                        const isStillVisible = isIntersecting(entry)
                        if (isStillVisible) {
                            this.showImage[element]=true;
                            target.classList.add("with-photo");
                        } else {
                            this.showImage[element]=false;
                            target.classList.remove("with-photo");
                        }
                        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                    });
                };
    
                this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

                // observer.observe(document.getElementById(res));
                const photos = document.querySelectorAll(`#${element} > .nine-box-item .photo-item`) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
               
                photos.forEach((photo, index) => {
                    this.observer.observe(photo);
                });

              

        });
     
    }
```

[Essa é uma referência do evento esperado](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-01/intersection-observer/)

[Aqui uma simulação do que tentei fazer](https://jsfiddle.net/w6hsfedo/2/)

Answer (score 0):

A solução encontrada para o problema foi resolvida através da criação de uma diretiva para uso do **IntersectionObserver**:

```
import {  Directive, ElementRef,  AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Output, Host, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({selector: "[enterTheViewportNotifier]"})
export class EnterTheViewportNotifierDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() visibilityChange = new EventEmitter<'VISIBLE' | 'HIDDEN'>();
 
  @Input()
  notDisconnect;

  @Input()
  private observer: IntersectionObserver;

  @Input()
  private eventChange: EventEmitter<any>;

  @Input()
  elementId;

  private _observer: IntersectionObserver;

  constructor(@Host() private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const options = {root: null,rootMargin: "0px",threshold: 1};

    if(this.elementId && this.eventChange) {
      this.eventChange.subscribe(e => {
        if(e && e.id == this.elementId) {
          this.visibilityChange.emit(e.event);
        }
      })
    }

    this._observer = this.observer ||  new IntersectionObserver(this._callback, options);

    this._observer.observe(this._elementRef.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(!this.notDisconnect) {
      this._observer.disconnect(); 
    } else{
      this._observer.unobserve(this._elementRef.nativeElement);
    } 
  }

  private _callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => 
        this.visibilityChange.emit(entry.isIntersecting ? 'VISIBLE' : 'HIDDEN'));
  };
}
```

Com a criação de alguns método para leitura das fotos que é chamado e finalizado conforme a interação do usuário no evento que é observado:

```
createShowPhotoIntersectionObservable() {
     
        if (this.hasPhoto && !this.showPhotoObserver) {
          try {
              const callback = (entries, observer) => {
                  entries.forEach((entry, i) => {
                      const currentIsVisible = !!this.showPhotoCheck[entry.target.id];
                      const event = entry.isIntersecting ? 'VISIBLE' : 'HIDDEN';
        
                      if(currentIsVisible != entry.isIntersecting) {
                        if(entry.target.id) {
                           this.photoVisibilityChange.emit({id: entry.target.id, event});
                        }
                      }
                  });
              }
      
            this.showPhotoObserver = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {root: null,rootMargin: "0px",threshold: 0});
          } catch(e) {
           
          }
        } 
      }
destructShowPhotoIntersectionObservable() {
      if(this.showPhotoObserver) {
        this.showPhotoObserver.disconnect();
       // this.showPhotoCheck = {};
        this.photoVisibilityChange.unsubscribe();
        this.photoVisibilityChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
      }
    }
  updateShowProfilePhotos(visibility, id) {
      this.showPhotoCheck[id] = visibility === 'VISIBLE'
  }
```

Que foi utilizado desta maneira na HTML:

```
<div 
   [attr.id]="'opt_'+item.id"
   enterTheViewportNotifier
   (visibilityChange)="updateShowProfilePhotos($event, 'opt_'+item.id)" 
   [elementId]="'opt_'+item.id"
   [observer]="showPhotoObserver"
   [eventChange]="photoVisibilityChange"
   notDisconnect="true"
   class="item-photo pl-2 pr-2 foto-minor" *ngIf="hasPhoto">
      <span *ngIf="showPhotoCheck['opt_'+item?.id] && hasPhoto" class="mask-photo"
 [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + (getPhotoUrl(item?.id) | async) + ') no-repeat center center',  'background-size': 'auto 28px, cover, contain'}"> 
      </span>
</div>
```